# Let $E$ and $F$ be normed spaces. If $\dim E = \infty$ and $F \neq \{0\}$, then there exists a discontinuous linear operator $T: E \rightarrow F$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't know how to define this linear operator. Can someone give me some  hints of how to define it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be a basis of $E$, and $f \in F \setminus \{0\}$. Let $a \colon \mathbf N \to B$ be an injection. Define $T$ on the basis by 
$$ T\bigl(a(n)\bigr) = n \|a(n)\|f $$
and $$ T(b) = 0, \qquad b \in B \setminus a[\mathbf N]$$
Now extend $T$ linearly to the whole of $E$. Then $T$ is linear, and
$$ \| T \| \ge \frac{\|T(a(n))\| }{\|a(n)\|}=  \frac{n\|a(n)\| \|f\|}{\|a(n)\|} = n\|f\| $$
hence $T$ is discontinuous.